# c# create Rss-Feed with the data out of the Database MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, rss

I want to create automaticlly the Rss-Feed with a controller in a MVC application. I have to use the data out of the database. The Table i need is Movie. Here is the code that i use at the moment:

```
public ContentResult GenerateRssFeed()
{
   string xmlString = "<div>Test</div>";
   CineStarEntities entities = new CineStarEntities();
   foreach (Movie movie in entities.Movie.Where(m => m.MovieID !=null).ToList()
   {
   }
   return Content(xmlString);`   
}
```

How can i write the foreach-Loop that i can outprint my data?

Comment: Take a look at this link, it should give you idea about the RSS feed genenration using syndication.  http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/71/easily-build-an-atom-or-rss-feed-with-csharp-and-the-syndication-namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. You have to add the attributes out of the database to an item. The Code is the following.

```
List<SyndicationItem> items = new List<SyndicationItem>();
CineStarEntities entities = new CineStarEntities();
foreach (Movie movie in entities.Movie.OrderBy(m => m.MovieTitle))
{
SyndicationItem item = new SyndicationItem();
item.Title = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.MovieTitle);
item.Content = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.Actors);

SyndicationItem item1 = new SyndicationItem();
item1.Content = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.Trailer);

SyndicationItem item2 = new SyndicationItem();
item2.Content = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.Duration.ToString());

SyndicationItem item3 = new SyndicationItem();
item3.Content = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.AgeRelease.ToString());

SyndicationItem item4 = new SyndicationItem();
item4.Content = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.Description);


SyndicationItem item6 = new SyndicationItem();
item6.Content = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.Direction);

SyndicationItem item7 = new SyndicationItem();
item7.Content = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.Direction);

SyndicationItem item8 = new SyndicationItem();
item8.Content = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.Production);

SyndicationItem item9 = new SyndicationItem();
item9.Content = new TextSyndicationContent(movie.Music);


items.Add(item);
items.Add(item1);
items.Add(item2);
items.Add(item3);
items.Add(item4);
items.Add(item6);
items.Add(item7);
items.Add(item8);
items.Add(item9);
```